# How to program MSP430FR6989 single chip

Tags: pcb-design, usb, msp430

So i have done microcontroller programming of the MSP430FR6989 with its own development board using TI's CCS. For this project, however, I need to program the individual chip to place into a custom PCB. How could I do so? I was thinking of implementing an USB connector into the PCB that would connect my PC to the MCU and do the programming as well as transfer data this way, but i am not sure it is that simple.

Comment: This chip has no USB support. See section 6.5 of the datasheet.

Answer (score 4):

This microcontroller doesn't even have USB, so that's out of the question.

You have to use the BSL (Bootstrap Loader), which is documented in a [User's Guide (SLAU550AB)](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau550ab/slau550ab.pdf?ts=1680092675599). If you want to make things simple for yourself, you can connect the programming / debug pod that's included on the development board to your own board with jumper wires. Alternatively, you could use the UART functionality of the BSL to connect directly to a computer via a serial port. In any case, you will have to make sure that you can perform the hardware BSL entry sequence to put the microcontroller into programming mode (via the RST/TEST pins).

Answer (score 4):

https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-FET?keyMatch=&tisearch=search-everything&usecase=hardware

[image: https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP-FET?keyMatch=&tisearch=search-everything&usecase=hardware]

If you use the TI MSP-FET programmer, you can download the firmware from your IDE, or by command-line ( using https://www.ti.com/tool/MSP430-FLASHER?keyMatch=MSP%20COMMAND%20LINE%20FLASHER) , you need just 4 connections to your target uC.

No additional chips or eproms or such required.  No special programming.

- Vcc
- GND
- nReset/SBWTDIO
- SBWTCK

Connect the MSP-FET programmer, via USB to your computer, and you can now program in circuit via the CSS IDE, or use TI's command-line program to download the binary firmware (generated by your IDE).

[image]

[image]

(Pins for a MSP430F5529 - Your chip will likely have different pin assignments.  See your datasheet.)

There are ways to add USB to your circuit.  The most obvious is to copy the development board design (which also likely has a bonus uart for data transfer).  However, this will cost you some extra chips.

Good luck!